# Unsetting onClickListener while animation is ongoing

Tags: android, animation

I'm developing an Android app and I've succeeded to put some images on the `Activity` and animate them. But then when I try to activate the animation I found that the `onClickListener` is not disabled. I've tried to do some research and tried to add an animation listener adapter and override the `onAnimationStart()/onAnimationEnd()` methods to try to disable the `onClickLister` by setting it *null*, except it didn't work and after some debugging I found that seems like the two methods are not called.

Here are some of my codes:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Skipped some of the variables declarations

private class AnimListAdapt extends AnimatorListenerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
        onClickPointer = null;
        Log.i("Animation","Animation starts");
        super.onAnimationStart(animation);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        Log.i("Animation","Animation ends");
        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
        onClickPointer = onClickObject;
    }

};

private AnimListAdapt animListAdapt;
private View.OnClickListener onClickPointer;
private View.OnClickListener onClickObject;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Skipped some of the variable assignments
    onClickObject = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            check((ImageView) view);
        }
    };

    onClickPointer = onClickObject;
    animListAdapt = new AnimListAdapt();

    img1View = (ImageView) findViewById (R.id.img1View);
    grids[4] = img1View;
    img1View.setOnClickListener(onClickPointer);

    img2View = (ImageView) findViewById (R.id.img2View);
    grids[4] = img2View;
    img2View.setOnClickListener(onClickPointer);
}
public void check (ImageView view) {
    int move;
if ((previous == null) || ((move = move(findGridNum(previous), findGridNum(view))) == NONE)) {
        if (previous == view) {
            view.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            previous = null;
        } else {
            if (previous !=null) {
                previous.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            }
            previous = view;
            view.setImageResource(R.drawable.crush_frame_tran);
        }
    } else {
        previous.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        switch (move) {
            case UP: {
                Log.i("moveCheck", "Up");
                animListAdapt.setUpAdapter(view);
                view.animate()
                        .setListener(animListAdapt);
                go_up(previous);
                go_down(view);
                break;
            }
            case DOWN: {
                Log.i("moveCheck", "Down");
                animListAdapt.setUpAdapter(view);
                view.animate()
                        .setListener(animListAdapt);
                go_down(previous);
                go_up(view);
                break;
            }
            case LEFT: {
                go_left(previous);
                animListAdapt.setUpAdapter(view);
                view.animate()
                        .setListener(animListAdapt);
                go_right(view);
                break;
            }
            case RIGHT: {
                go_right(previous);
                animListAdapt.setUpAdapter(view);
                view.animate()
                        .setListener(animListAdapt);
                go_left(view);
            }
        }
        previous = null;
    }
}
public void go_right (View view) {
    view.startAnimation(to_right);
}
public void go_left (View view) {
    view.startAnimation(to_left);
}
public void go_up (View view) {
    view.startAnimation(to_up);
}
public void go_down (View view) {
    view.startAnimation(to_down);
}
}
```

As you can see I tried to call out logs in the both `onAnimationStart()` and `onAnimationEnd()` method, I figured that those logs are not appearing. I'm not sure what's wrong that makes my codes don't work.

Please help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mToolbar = mPopupContents.findViewById( R.web.toolbar );
TranslateAnimation anim =
    new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, -60, 0);
anim.setDuration(1000);
anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation a) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "---- animation start listener called"  );
        }
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation a) {}
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation a) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "---- animation end listener called"  );
        }
    });
mToolbar.startAnimation(anim);
```

look at this example for `startAnimation()` you need to pass an instance of an animation.But in your code you just past a view ,so where is your animation? that's why `onAnimationStart`is not working.

you don't need to do it like this but i think you did move something , to that you might create that animation instance, pass that  to `startAnimation()`

Comment: Thanks! I altered the code and created a `AnimationListener` instead of the `AnimatiorListenerAdapter`.
Though may I ask what is an `AnimatorListenerAdapter`? I've seen some people using `View.animator().setListener(AnimatorListenerAdapter a)` to put the `AnimatorListenerAdapter` into the animation instance (?) of a view and implements the `onAnimationStart` and `onAnimationEnd` in there.